# sub domain to act as proxy for another sub domain? apache / htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, proxy, subdomain, reverse-proxy

**I have a subdomain:**

subdomain.mydomain.com

**On my site are 5 images taken from a table which are links from another site:**

*example:* subdomain.anothersite.com/image/123.jpg

**If i rename the links in the table to change the domain from**

subdomain.anothersite.com/images/123.jpg   *to*   subdomain.mydomain.com/images/123.jpg

**Can I then setup some sort of reverse proxy which means any url from that table will show as:**

subdomain.mydomain.com/images/123.jpg - *but is actually showing the content from* subdomain.anothersite.com/images/123.jpg

?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a question for serverfault.com.  stack overflow is for programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually achieve that by setting up a CNAME through your DNS from `subdomain.mydomain.com` to `subdomain.anothersite.com` . The domain will be essentially masked and all your users see is `subdomain.mydomain.com/images/123.jpg`